# Не понимаю задачу по приведению типов объектов

Tags: java

Задача из подпункта по приведению типов объектов:

```
//What is wrong in the following code?

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object fruit = new Fruit();
    Object apple = (Apple)fruit;
  }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
}

class Fruit {
}
```

Что тут не так?

Comment: @panzermarin, почему мы явно не можем считать любую машину за жигули?

Comment: Но именно эта машина есть жигули, и поэтому объект класса Автомобиль явно приводим к классу Жигули.
Что хочет услышать автор книги в ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: @panzermarin, нет, у этой машины вообще нет марки.

Comment: Так и понял что здесь не так

Comment: Именно в данном конкретном коде я вообще никакой ошибки не вижу, за исключением одной логической - зачем приводить к типу Apple, если слева все равно стоит Object?

Comment: Так объясни пожалуйста, а то не догоняю)

Comment: @panzermarin: А где, вы считаете, должна быть ошибка, и почему?

Comment: Автор книги задает вопрос "What is wrong in the following code?".
Я не вижу проблем в коде, кроме избыточности.

Comment: @panzermarin

![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/tdElPBu.png)

Comment: @panzermarin: Проблем нету. Этот код ожидаемо упадёт с exception'ом в полном соответствии с правилами языка.

Comment: @panzermarin: Должен упасть. Т. к. `fruit` имеет runtime-тип `Fruit`, но не является `Apple`.

Comment: Вся , я понял. Перехожу на ArrayList )))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Каждое яблоко - фрукт, но не каждый фрукт - яблоко. Мы можем работать с яблоком, как с фруктом, но не можем привести фрукт к яблоку.

Comment: Почему не можем? Это называется "Explicit casting"

Comment: @panzermarin потому что фруктом может быть апельсин, например. Вот достаете вы из черной коробки фрукт и говорите: "Ооо щас яблоко сожру", т.е. заранее думаете, что это яблоко, хотя не знаете наверняка, какой фрукт вытащите. И вот если вы вытащите не яблоко, но назовете это яблоком - это будет ошибкой.

Comment: @panzermarin, потому что если фрукт окажется не яблоком, вы словите `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Оооо, спасибо. Теперь понял!